# Disable theming for HTML button

Tags: asp.net, css

In my web application I've set the CSS style for all the buttons like,

```
input[type=button], button
{
  //
}
```

If I want to use some other CSS class for a particular button, If its a ASP button I can simply use the property `EnableTheming="false"`.

but I've a `html button`, for this I need to disable theming. I tried `EnableTheming`, but its not working. How can I do this, can anyone help me here.

I tried to setting the removeClass using jQuery like,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $(":button").removeClass("marked");

      });
  </script>
```

but, its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class has something like this

```
input[type=button], button
{
  border:1px solid #fco;
  padding : 0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Do this to make the style default

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $(":button").css({"border":"", "padding":"", "margin":""});
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

you can remove the css class using jquery

```
$(":button").removeClass("marked");
```

if you want to add class

```
$(":button").addClass("marked");
```

Comment: thanks for ur response Jagz, what is `marked` here, is it cssclass name?

Comment: fine, I'll try and let u know

Comment: how can I mention the name for this 'input[type=button], button'